# gfs.files.findOne(): cannot find files of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs-stream, multer-gridfs-storage

Actually, I want to use `gfs` variable outside of the function. But I'm getting `undefined`. I'm using Node.js for the back-end and using Express.js framework.
Please take a quick look at what I'm doing.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); // Version = 6.2.10
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream"); // Version = 1.1.1

// Creating the mongodb connection
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once("open", async () => {
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
  console.log(gfs); // Returns the Grid object
});
console.log(gfs); // Returns "undefined" ===> Need to solve the bug here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem what worked for me is

```
const gfs = conn.once("open", () => {
  
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
  return gfs;
});
```